# Let q be a positive rational number, $q \neq 1$, prove that log(q) is irrational.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

in this case log means $log_{e}$.

What I've learned before is that to prove a number irrational use a contradiction proof by assuming it's rational. Do I do that in this case? If so, how do I start the proof?

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $e$ is transcendental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said. Assume that $$\log q=\frac ab,$$ with $a,b\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$. Then $q=e^{a/b}$. Then $e=q^{b/a}$. So $e$ would be a root of 
$$
p(x)=x^a-q^b.
$$
But $e$ is transcendental (i.e., not algebraic).

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to showing that *$e^{x}$ is irrational if $x$ is a non-zero rational number*. There are many proofs available for this property of $e$ the first of which was given by Lambert [based on continued fraction expansion of $\tanh x$](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/05/irrationality-of-pi-lamberts-proof-contd.html) (the same technique yields irrationality of $\pi$). Another common [proof was given by Ivan M. Niven](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/476985/72031) in his wonderful book *Irrational Numbers*. And a [totally different proof was given by C. L. Siegel](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2015/08/irrationality-of-exp-x.html). As mentioned in Martin Argerami's answer the result is also a simple corollary of the fact that [*$e$ is transcendental*](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/Herstein%20Beweis%20der%20Transzendenz%20der%20Zahl%20e.pdf).