# Is this a valid proof that $ e^{\pi^2} $ is irrational?

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers, pi

[Proving the irrationality of $e^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476939/proving-the-irrationality-of-en)

This essentially proves $e^n \ $  is irrational for all possible values of n and
since $ e^{\pi^2} $   is essentially $e^{\pi\times\pi}$  and this fits the  $e^n \ $ category so does that make it irrational?

Comment: Huh???????????????

Comment: $n$ is supposed to be an integer. Is $\pi^2$ an integer?

Comment: No, this does not prove that $\mathrm{e}^{\pi^2}$ is irrational; the proof that you cite assumes that $n$ is a natural number.

Comment: That link shows that $e^n$ is irrational for positive integers $n$.  $\pi^2$ is not a positive integer

Comment: If $n$ was arbitrary, you could write $e^{\ln 2}=2$ irrational.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help

Comment: To the original question:  I, for one, don't know if the transcendence of $e^{\pi^2}$ has been shown (surely it is transcendental, but proving it is another matter). Of course, someone else may know more about it. The transcendence of $e^{\pi}$ follows from the [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, $e^{\pi^2}$ isn't just “essentially” $e^{\pi\times\pi}$; they're the same thing. And the question to which you have posted a link is about the irrationality of the numbers of the form $e^n$, with $n$ natural. Since $\pi^2\notin\mathbb N$, no, $e^{\pi^2}$ doesn't fit this category.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 3):

No. The link shows that $e^n$ is irrational for any *natural number* $n$. But $\pi^2$ isn't a natural number, so that result doesn't apply. Note that there absolutely *are* exponents $x$ for which $e^x$ is rational - e.g. $e^{\ln 2}=2,$ and so on.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The answers to that question only show that $e^n$ is irrational for any *positive integer $n$*.  This would only apply to $e^{\pi^2}$ if $\pi^2$ were a positive integer, which it is not.