# Prove ${e}^{x}$, $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ is irrational

Tags: exponential-function, irrational-numbers

I was thinking of random problems in my head when this came to mind. But I have absolutely no idea how to solve it, so I can't show my attempts. Please help me with this.

**Prove $\boldsymbol{e^x}$, $\boldsymbol{x\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is irrational**

Comment: this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476939/proving-the-irrationality-of-en may interest you probaly

Comment: not true for $x=0$